# Objective-C, member variables and class variables

Tags: objective-c, class

i need some help on understanding how to use class/member variable from a instance method in Objective-C.

Any snipplet / example is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't have class variables, and what you call a member variable is called an instance variable. Instance variables can be referenced by name from within an instance method. And if you need the behavior of a class variable, you can use a file-level static instead.

Here's a very quick sample:

*Foo.h*

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSString *foo;
}
@end
```

*Foo.m*

```
static NSString *bar;

@implementation Foo
- (void)foobar {
    foo = @"test"; // assigns the ivar
    bar = @"test2"; // assigns the static
}
@end
```

Comment: And you will use it like : Foo *myFoo = [[Foo alloc] init]; [myFoo foobar]; [myFoo release];

Comment: Thanks for your fast respone, my idea is to have a class NSMutableDictionary that all instances of a object shares, would that be a correct way of design or im I missing something?

Comment: If you need a shared dictionary, that works fine. You'd want a file-level static in the .m for the NSMutableDictionary, and you'll likely want to create it in your `+initialize` method (to ensure it exists before any instances access it). If you ever need to touch this object off of the main thread, you should use a GCD dispatch queue to serialize access to it - otherwise, just go ahead and use it like normal. Note that you'll need to stick an owned instance in the variable, e.g. `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`. And never release it (as the class itself never goes away).